# Laravel , database record update is shown after page refresh

Tags: php, mysql, session, controller, laravel-5

I implemented a simple view count with session . It is working as I expected but the **view_count** value is updated immediately in database but is not shown in view. I should reload page to get the expected result. 
*Here is my code*

```
public function viewArticle($slug){
    $article = Article::where('slug',$slug)->first();

    $articleKey = 'article_' . $article->id;

    // Check session exists, if not then increment view count and create session key

    if (!Session::get($articleKey)) {
        Article::where('id', $article->id)->increment('view_count');
        Session::put($articleKey, 1);
    }

    return view('main');
}
```

*I pass multiple variables to view , but removed them to be specific to question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not reload the `$article`, it remain the same, try this instead:

```
public function viewArticle($slug){
    $article = Article::where('slug',$slug)->first();

    $articleKey = 'article_' . $article->id;

    // Check session exists, if not then increment view count and create session key

    if(!Session::get($articleKey)){
        $article->view_count++;
        $article->save();
        Session::put($articleKey,1);
    }

    return view('main');
}
```